# Como autenticar o usuário de uma outra pagina de login

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma pagina de login para fazer a autenticação em um outra pagina de login, mas esta dando erro. Aonde estou errando?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Obtém as informações do formulário de login
var form = document.getElementById("login-form");
var email = form.elements['email'].value;
var senha = form.elements['password'].value;

// Envia as informações do formulário para o servidor para autenticação
fetch('https://pagina.htm/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({email: email, senha: password}),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
  if (data.success) {
    // Redireciona o usuário para a página protegida
    window.location.href = "interna.htm";
  } else {
    // Exibe uma mensagem de erro
    alert("E-mail ou senha incorretos");
  }
});

    </script>

<form id="login-form" method="POST">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
   <a href="interna.htm"><button id="bnt" type="submit">Acessar Conta</button></a>
<form>
```

Comment: *"mas esta dando erro"* que erro? já fez debug pra perceber o problema?

Answer (score -2):

Pode ser que tenha alguns problemas no seu código que gerado um erro, mas para conseguir te ajudar eu teria que ter mais alguns detalhes. Então analisando o código eu vou apontar alguns detalhes que podem estar influenciado no seu problema.

#### Problema 1:

Analisando o seu código pode ser que o problema seja na maneira que você está recuperando os dados do seu formulário, talvez seja melhor a seguinte abordagem:

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var senha = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

u
Já que você tem os ids atribuidos no seus inputs, isso ajuda ao javascript a identificar o elemento e a ser mais fácil de extrar os valores dos mesmos.

#### Problema 2:

Notei que no seu código html o seu elemento `button` está envolido por uma tag `a`, o que pode fazer você ser redirecionado a página `interna.html`. Sugiro que você remova essa tag `a` e deixe apenas o `button`.

#### Problema 3:

O seu código em javascript está sendo adicionado ao carregar a página, sugiro que você envolva o seu código de autenticação em uma função que é disparado ao clicar no seu button, você pode implementar dessa forma:

```js
document.getElementById("bnt").onclick = function() {

var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var senha = document.getElementById("password").value;

// Envia as informações do formulário para o servidor para autenticação
fetch('https://pagina.htm/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({email: email, senha: password}),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
  if (data.success) {
    // Redireciona o usuário para a página protegida
    window.location.href = "interna.htm";
  } else {
    // Exibe uma mensagem de erro
    alert("E-mail ou senha incorretos");
  }
});

}
```

Isso vai garantir que ao clicar no elemento o ID `btn` ao ser clicado seja acionado a função de autenticação

#### Problema 4

Notei na sua chamado do fetch que você efetua uma chamada POST para o link `https://pagina.htm/login`, certifique-se que essa página seja um código que volte uma resposta em JSON para que ele obtenha resposta.

Acredito que essas podem ser as possíveis causas do seu código não funcionar como devia, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fiz as correções que sugeriu, mas agora esta dando o seguite erro:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
O que pode ser?

Comment: Acredito que esse problema seja devido a você não ter o script do fetch disponível no JS Vanilla, o que você pode utilizar no lugar seria o Ajax. Aqui está um link que pode te ajudar a fazer essa substituição: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Consegui eliminar o erro, só que não consigo redirecionar a pagina! Alguma dica?

Comment: Acredito que o comando window.location.href na parte que você indica sucesso resolva, geralmente está no método success do Ajax.